# Go Gorrilla Mux will keep redirecting with 301 while using StrictSlash(true), how to return the json

Tags: go

This is part of my main function that I use for my end points

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.StrictSlash(true)
r.HandleFunc("/", test)
r.HandleFunc("/feature/list/", a.FeatureListHandler)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r))
```

but when I `curl localhost:8080/feature/list` I get

```
<a hef="/feature/list">Moved Permanently</a>
```

However, when I `curl localhost:8080/feature/list/` I get my json.

How do I make it so that both routes will return the json I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, it seems this is the expected behaviour for when `StrictSlash` is `true`:

http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Router.StrictSlash

Perhaps you can set it to `false` and then define both routes separately?

```
r.StrictSlash(false)
r.HandleFunc("/feature/list", a.FeatureListHandler)
r.HandleFunc("/feature/list/", a.FeatureListHandler)
```

Comment: Hum.. ok, that just seems silly, I was trying to to avoid that solution.

Comment: @richard_d_sim: agreed, but since gorilla seems to redirect from one to the other when setting StrictSlash in true, this solution might be the only way to have each endpoint respond directly. Note that you can write a wrapper function that can receive one endpoint and make the two mappings so that you don't pollute your code with copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following middleware to deal with this

```
func suffixMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // remove the trailing slash from our URL Path if it's not root
        if r.URL.Path != "/" {
            r.URL.Path = strings.TrimSuffix(r.URL.Path, "/")
        }

        // Call the next handler, which can be another middleware in the chain, or the final handler.
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Then you pass your router through such as:
`(suffixMiddleware(router))`